# gpg - Cannot import public key from asc file

Tags: gnupg

I'm using Windows 10 Home with GPG version 2.2.19.

Whenever I try to import the asc file for Tor Browser using the command `gpg --import torbrowser-install-win64-9.0.7_en-US.exe.asc`, I get this fancy error:

```
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

Likewise, this also happens when trying to verify the installer itself with the key file by using the command `gpg --verify torbrowser-install-win64-9.0.7_en-US.exe.asc torbrowser-install-win64-9.0.7_en-US.exe`:

```
gpg: Signature made 03/22/20 10:42:09 Eastern Daylight Time
gpg:                using RSA key EB774491D9FF06E2
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
```

Trying the answers in the tons of other guides here haven't helped whatsoever. Can I get some help?

Comment: As the name indicates, that file is a _signature_ which can be verified (in conjunction with the data since it is detached, which is obvious from the size though not the name), and is not a _key_ so it cannot be imported. To get the Tor key, click the obvious link on the download page to https://support.torproject.org/tbb/how-to-verify-signature/ and read the section Fetching the Tor Developers key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.asc` file contains the signature. To verify it, you need three things:

1. The signed file (your tor browser download)
2. The public key it was signed with
3. The `.asc` file itself

You do already have the signed `.exe` file and the signature. Next you must fetch the public key. You can do this automatically with the following command:

```
gpg --auto-key-locate nodefault,wkd --locate-keys torbrowser@torproject.org
```

This is the output of the command on my machine:

```
gpg: key 4E2C6E8793298290: public key "Tor Browser Developers (signing key) <torbrowser@torproject.org>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              imported: 1
pub  rsa4096 2014-12-15 [C] [expires: 2020-08-24]
     EF6E286DDA85EA2A4BA7DE684E2C6E8793298290 uid
          [ unknown] Tor Browser Developers (signing key) <torbrowser@torproject.org
sub  rsa4096 2018-05-26 [S] [expires: 2020-09-12]
```

Comparing the fingerprint with the fingerprint posted on the [tor website](https://support.torproject.org/tbb/how-to-verify-signature/) is a good idea at that point.

Next you export the public key to a keyring:

```
gpg --output tor.kr --export 0xEF6E286DDA85EA2A4BA7DE684E2C6E8793298290
```

This command uses the currently valid fingerprint to identify the key, which it needs to export. A future reader might have to use another one, if the key has changed in the meantime.

Finally you can verify the signature with the following command:

```
gpgv --keyring tor.kr torbrowser-install-win64-9.0.7_en-US.exe.asc torbrowser-install-win64-9.0.7_en-US.exe
```

The output will tell you, if the signature verification worked. Hopefully you see something like this:

```
gpgv: Signature made So 22 Mar 2020 10:37:51 EDT
gpgv:                using RSA key EB774491D9FF06E2
gpgv: Good signature from "Tor Browser Developers (signing key) <torbrowser@torproject.org>"
```

In case it failed, it will look something like this instead:

```
gpgv: Signature made So 22 Mar 2020 10:37:51 EDT
gpgv:                using RSA key EB774491D9FF06E2
gpgv: BAD signature from "Tor Browser Developers (signing key) <torbrowser@torproject.org>"
```

Comment: Yeah, that did indeed work for me! Thank you so much. I've marked this as the answer to this question.